# php проблемы с сохранением gif изображений

Tags: php

здравствуйте, вообщем есть функция сохранения jpg картинок

```
if(exif_imagetype($tmp) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { 

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp); 
$path = $this->createdir().$name.'.jpg'; 
imagejpeg($image, $this->cdndir.$path, 100); 
imagedestroy($image); 
}
```

а вот такая же самая, но для ГИФ

```
if(exif_imagetype($tmp) == IMAGETYPE_GIF && $this->gif) { 
header("Content-Type: image/gif"); 

$image = imagecreatefromgif($tmp); 
$path = $this->createdir().$name.'.gif'; 
imagegif($image, $this->cdndir.$path); 
imagedestroy($image); 
}
```

но дело в том что при сохранении, картинка то имеет .gif расширение и тип, но анимация полностью пропадает и она становится статичной, не подскажите что за бред? уже нервов нет

Comment: это не бред. Так оно и работает. При ресайзе тож аналогичные проблемы.  Даже вкантакт анимимрованные гифки "делает, использует" не как рисунки, а как документы. А  из чего вы создаете (пересоздаете) гифки? Может ПОСЛЕ проверок на вшывость перемещать их в место хранения, а в браузере масштабировать их width и height. НО как правильно анимацию ресайзить я не зн. Может есть соответствующие php-библиотеки?

Comment: вот еще https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может лучше использовать `move_uploaded_file` ( https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php )?

```
 if (fileformat == XX and filesize == YY and ... прочие проверки){

     if (! move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$cdndir/$newname")){
        echo 'file not saved';
        exit;
       } 

 }else{
       echo 'file is not image';    //или не прошел проверку по иным парамертам (возможно слишком большой)
       exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что `imagecreatefromgif` сохраняет только первый кадр.

Возможно вам помогут `file_get_contents` и `file_put_contents`

```
$gif_image = file_get_contents("<URL анимации>"); 
header("Content-Type: image/gif"); 
echo $gif_image;
```

P.S. Либо погуглите какие нибудь библиотеки для сохранения анимации `:)`